# Can linear programing be used in Model Predictive Control?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization, optimal-control, model-predictive-control

I'm trying to implement Model Predictive Control onto a small micro controller. I know that is not "possible", but I want to minimize the "unnecessary" tools that are avaiable inside "regular" Model Predictive Control from e.g MATLAB Control Toolbox.

Let's begin with the discrete SISO state space model.

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k)$$
$$y(k) = Cx(k)$$

Then we create our extended model with controllability matrix $\Phi$ and our lower triangular toeplitz matrix that are a combination of observabillity matrix and controllability matrix.

$$\Phi = \begin{bmatrix}
CA\\ 
CA^2\\ 
CA^3\\ 
\vdots \\
CA^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\Gamma = \begin{bmatrix}
CB & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
CAB & CB & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
CA^2B & CAB & CB & 0 & 0\\ 
 \vdots  & \vdots  &\vdots  & \ddots  & 0 \\ 
CA^{n-2} B& CA^{n-3} B  & CA^{n-4} B & \dots  & CA^{n-j} B 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $j=n$

Now we can find our inputs by solving: (Only works for SISO models, else, use pseudo-inverse or solve with least squares)

$$U = (\Gamma)^{-1}(R-\Phi x)$$

Where $R$ is our desire output, e.g reference and $x$ is our initial state. Normally estimated from a Kalman filter.

If I have the model values, with a sample rate as $h=0.5$

```
A =

   0.89559   0.37735
  -0.37735   0.51825

B =

   0.10441
   0.37735

C =

   1   0
```

Then my $U$ would be if our prediction is $N = 40$ long.

```
   239.4510
  -301.5661
   301.1320
  -208.4868
   222.4277
  -141.9374
   166.1560
   -94.3562
   125.9231
   -60.3368
    97.1576
   -36.0137
    76.5909
   -18.6233
    61.8862
    -6.1896
    51.3728
     2.7002
    43.8559
     9.0562
    38.4815
    13.6006
    34.6389
    16.8497
    31.8916
    19.1727
    29.9273
    20.8336
    28.5229
    22.0211
    27.5188
    22.8702
    26.8009
    23.4772
    26.2876
    23.9113
    25.9206
    24.2216
    25.6582
    24.4434
```

And this it hot it looks like when $U$ is normal and $U > 0$ only.

[image]

We can clearly see that the inputs is very...jumpy. That's not good, because the model is not jumpy at all. This happens because the controllability matrix is a impulse response.

So my question if I can change the values of $U$ by setting constraints and a objective function that we want to minimize $J(U)$ where $x$ is our initial state vector.

$$J(U) = -R + \Phi x + \Gamma U$$

With subject to:
$$ u_{lb} <= U <= u_{ub}$$

I have an idea here! Hence the $\Gamma$ is a lower triangular, I don't need to use inverse at all to solve $U$. I can use Gaussian Elimination to solve $U$.

Step 0:

- Set the long vector $U= 0$ to begin with
- Compute initial $J(0)$

Step 1:

- Solve the $U_i$ from the extended model above

Step 2:

- If $U_i < u_{lb}$ then $U_i = u_{lb}$ or if $U_i > u_{ub}$ then $U_i = u_{ub}$

Step 3:

- Check if $J(U)$ become larger or smaller with $U_i$ as argument.
- If $J(U)$ become larger with $U_i$, then say that past input is equal as current input e.g $U_i = U_{i-1}$, then continue.
- If $J(U)$ become smaller with $U_i$, then just continue.

I know that this is not real linear programming. It's just a simplification for a unique problem in control theory.

** Question:**

What do you think about this? Will it work to minimize this? Or do you have another idea? Notice that I'm going to write everything in plain C language, so don't except that I'm going to use large libraries. ;)

$$J(U) = -R + \Phi x + \Gamma U$$
With subject to:
$$ u_{lb} <= U <= u_{ub}$$

**Edit:**

I made a test by writing this MATLAB/Octave script. I did not use a cost function here, because it result more jumpy values. All I did was to solve a linear system by using Gaussian elimination with constraints.

Model:

```
>> sysd
sysd =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    A =

       1.13489   1.00000
      -0.47237   0.00000

    B =

       0.047496
       0.036873

    C =

       1   0

    D = 0
    delay = 0
    type = SS
    sampleTime =  0.50000

>> [K, U] = mpc(sysd.A, sysd.B, sysd.C, [0;0], 40, 10, 0);
```

And the function script

```
function [K, U] = mpc (A, B, C, x, N, r, lb)

  ## Find matrix
  PHI = phiMat(A, C, N);
  GAMMA = gammaMat(A, B, C, N);
  K = inv(GAMMA)*(r-PHI*x);

  ## Solve first with no constraints
  U = solve(PHI, GAMMA, x, N, r, 0, 0, false);

  ## Then use the last U as upper bound
  U = solve(PHI, GAMMA, x, N, r, lb, U(end), true);

end

function U = solve(PHI, GAMMA, x, N, r, lb, ub, constraints)
  ## Set U
  U = zeros(N, 1);

  ## Iterate Gaussian Elimination
  for i = 1:N

    ## Solve u
    if(i == 1)
      u = (r - PHI(i,:)*x)/GAMMA(i,i)
    else
      u = (r - PHI(i,:)*x - GAMMA(i,1:i-1)*U(1:i-1) )/GAMMA(i,i)
    end

    ## Constraints 
    if(constraints == true)
      if(u > ub)
        u = ub;
      elseif(u < lb)
        u = lb;
      end
    end

    ## Save u
    U(i) = u
  end
end

function PHI = phiMat(A, C, N)

  ## Create the special Observabillity matrix
  PHI = [];
  for i = 1:N
    PHI = vertcat(PHI, C*A^i);
  end

end

function GAMMA = gammaMat(A, B, C, N)

  ## Create the lower triangular toeplitz matrix
  GAMMA = [];
  for i = 1:N
    GAMMA = horzcat(GAMMA, vertcat(zeros((i-1)*size(C*A*B, 1), size(C*A*B, 2)),cabMat(A, B, C, N-i+1)));
  end

end

function CAB = cabMat(A, B, C, N)

  ## Create the column for the GAMMA matrix
  CAB = [];
  for i = 0:N-1
    CAB = vertcat(CAB, C*A^i*B);
  end

end
```

By inserting an arbitrary SS-model. This gave me the result.
[image]

And the output response - Seems more as the reality. Not sure how "real" it is.
[image]

Here is the output response from the none constrained inputs. The reality does not look like this.
[image]

Comment: Why all the ad-hoc mess when the problem you have arise from the fact that you are using a bad performance measure (dead-beat control) when deriving the control sequence $U$. Standard quadratic performance with some penalty on $U$ and you won't see this shattering effect (and computational cost is the same, a back-solve of a linear system)

Comment: @JohanLöfberg The reason why it become this shattering effect is due to the controllability matrix. I don't know how to remove this. When I try GNU Octaves QP-solver, I won't get this kind of shattering effect. But QP sovers is to advanced for a micro controller. I'm trying to implement some kind of input optimization onto a embedded system. QP solvers are too huge and advanced. Need something small that fits. And there is no idea to getting a bigger micro controller.

Comment: You are solving a linear system with your current approach, and you would have precisely the same complexity (solving a linear system) if you formulated a quadratic performance measure. If data is constant, all you have to do on-line is state-feedback in both cases. If data changes and you really need to compute $\Gamma^{-1}$ or correspondingly $(\Gamma^T Q_1\Gamma + Q_2)^{-1}$ (or more precisely solve a linear system with matrices) nothing forces you to use an advanced direct  method for either approach. Both can be done using some iterative approach involving matrix-vector multiplication

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Sorry. I don't understand what you are saying. Are you saying that QP programming does not need to be advanced? I haven't found a simple library in C for that. I have updated my question above.

Comment: No, I am saying that the computational complexity of finding $U$ such that $Y = 0$ and minimizing $Y^TQ_1Y + U^TQ_2U$ have the same computational complexity as they both boil down to solving a linear system of equations, and this can be done using either direct methods or indirect methods. Hence, no reason to use a dead-beat formulation with poor control properties when you just as well can use a classical quadratic performance measure which typically is easy to tune for good performance.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I don't know how to code a quadratic solver in C that fits embedded systems with low ram and low cpu hz.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg What do you think about my solution above? I'm using the classical least square solving method to find the $U$ vector and then I take the end of the $U$ vector and use it as upper bound limit. I'm also using Gaussian elimination with constraints for every iteration.

Comment: As I said, if you can do vector operations, you can easily solve linear systems of equations, and thus minimize quadratic performance measures. You are most likely re-inventing square wheels.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg But isint QP solver numerical cost expensive? I'm mean that first we need to set up the objective function, find the equality KKT equation and then use active sets method to solve for inequality constraints. That sounds very expensive due to the hardware is limited.

Comment: But you are not solving an optimization problem exactly, so no reason to solve a QP either. You can simply use the quadratic cost, and analytically compute the optimal solution which simply is a linear system of equations (i.e. no more complicated than what you are doing now) and then use any ad-hoc stuff you want to saturate the control. That way you know you are doing something sensible as the control will inherit all good properties from LQ once it goes unsaturated (heck, why even pose it as an optimization problem, the optimal unconstrained solution is linear state-feedback).

Comment: In other words: What's wrong with simply saturating the LQ control. It's a hack, but so is your current code, but with the added complication that you have no grasp on the properties of that controller

Comment: @JohanLöfberg If I saturate the inputs, then the output might become jumpy. Se above.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg How mutch work do you think it is to implement a QP solver onto a 512 kB RAM with 180 Mhz microprocessor? Impossible? Or will it work good as well if I select the last input of vector $U$ instead of first one in vector $U$? If I select the last input of vector $U$, then the system will be very smooth, according to what I have computed above.

Comment: Of course it is possible but it depends on the framework you are using, how large the problem is, what precision requirements you have, how low-level you accept to go, which algorithm you want to implement etc, etc.

Comment: and as I already said: The "jumpy" input you see is simply because you have a bad way of formulating the control problem, when you try to find an an input which drives the output to the reference in one sample (dead-beat). For many system you will automatically get a solution which goes back and forth (to get to the reference in one step, you have to null out one state by driving the other state to some non-zero position, and then in the next stage, you have inserted energy in that state which you now have to drive to zero...

Comment: and I don't see the problem really. A saturated LQ controller performs reference tracking easily here

Comment: @JohanLöfberg So you mean, after computing the $U$ vector from the extended SS-model above, then all I need to do is select the first $U$ and saturate it e.g $U > 0$ ? That will work in real time control?

Comment: If you mean the $U$ which minimizes $(Y-R)^TQ_1(Y-R) + (U-U_{steady})^TQ_2(U-U_{steady})$ (and can be obtained by solving a linear system of equations), yes. Except I talked about LQ, which is a linear state feedback minimizing the inifinite horizon version of that

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I'm taking about $U = \Gamma ^{-1} (r -  \Phi x)$

Comment: and as I've said repeatedly, using that dead-beat strategy wil give you a horrible controller. Note also that it corresponds to using $Q_2=0$, so why not let your self use the tuning capabilities you have in control penalty to get rid off the shattering caused by using a dead-beat controller.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I was reading Karl Johan Åströms book about Adaptive Control and according to his resarch, using that kind of dead-beat equation (solving with ordinary least squares), will result a good control result. Sure, I'm know that quadratic programming is much better, but it have a cost too. Trying to choose between qudratic programming and solving the equation with least squares + saturation. All into a embedded system with recursive least square as identification method. It's not for science, more for my own hobby projects.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Also Lennart Ljung, your college, wrote the book "Multivariabla och olinjära metoder 2003" and described MPC with solving the equation with ordinary least squares gives a good result.

Comment: The expression I am using is least-squares so I don't see what you are talking about or arguing for. Minimizing quadratic function and solving a linear system of equations is effectively the same thing. I am not arguing for full-fledged QP. I am talking about simply saturating the unconstrained QP solution (which you can do with state feedback even). The fact that your dead-beat control gives a poor controller is pretty evident in the example you supply. Indeed, the whole premise of your question is the fact that you obtain poor control.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I understand. But didn't I solve the QP-problem above by using least squares? Or did I miss something? Oh, you mean that I should have solved $U = (\Gamma^T \Gamma + \alpha I)^{-1}\Gamma^T(r-\Phi x)$ instead of $U = \Gamma^{-1}(r-\Phi x)$? The reason why I solve  for $U = \Gamma^{-1}(r-\Phi x)$ is because $\Gamma$ is a lower triangular toeplitz matrix = can be solved by Gaussian elimination. Only works for SISO models.

Comment: Since you have managed to solve $r = \Phi x + \Gamma U$, you have equivalently minimized $(\Phi x + \Gamma U - r)^T(\Phi x + \Gamma U - r)$. Both boil down to solving a linear system of equation, one (implicitly) working $\Phi ^{-1}$ and one $(\Phi^T\Phi) ^{-1}$. Minor linear algebra differences, one leaving you with a horrible control sequence, same with the other but that one easily generalizes to create much better tuning by adding penalty on $U$ etc.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg So you recommend me to solve the unconstrainted QP problem e.g the equation $U=(\Gamma^T\Gamma+\alpha I)^{-1}\Gamma^T(r−\phi x)$ and then tune in $\alpha$ and then also saturate the $U$ vector? What if I actually minimize $1/2x^TQx + c^Tx$ Where $Q = \Gamma^T \Gamma$, It would be the same as $U=(\Gamma^T\Gamma)^{-1}\Gamma^T(r−\phi x)$ ?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Do you have some kind of recommendation if I want to have this as an adaptive controller? I mean a controller that I should only start and then it tune in by it self. I'm well known with recursive least square. I have an Idea and that is by selecting the last input $U$ in the dead beat control. I have tried some simulations and it might works for systems with first or second order model.

Comment: why use unconstrained QP cost when you just as well can compute the infinite horizon solution which is LQ state feedback

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Because infinite horizon solution with riccati equations is to much cost expensive?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Just a curious question. Will GPC behave the same, if I just saturate the input vector $U$ during solving, as MPC if I only put constraints on $U$? Trying to use Gaussian elimination to solve $U =(\Gamma ^T \Gamma + \alpha I)^{-1}\Gamma ^T(R - \Phi x)$ and for each step I solve $U_i$, I saturate it with lower boud limit and upper bound limit. It would be the same if I have the objective function $\frac{1}{2}U^TQU + c^TU$ , where $Q = \Gamma^T \alpha I \Gamma$, with subject too $s.t lb <= U <= ub$ ?

Comment: GPC is essentially unconstrained MPC, thus with input constraints you would necessarily 
 saturate the solution a-posteriori.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Sorry, did not understand the last "the solution a posteriori". By the way! I tried to use gaussian elimination for solving $U = (\Gamma ^T \Gamma + \alpha I)^{-1}\Gamma^T(R - \Phi x)$ with $\alpha$ as a small number e.g $0.1$ and it gives very smooth values. Also put some internal integration inside the model (one pole at zero). Gives even better result. So that might be the reason why I did get jumpy values at my question.

Comment: Yes, as I've said the whole time, not penalizing $u$ (i.e. $\alpha=0$ or equivalently trying to solve $Y=R$) is a recipe for bad control, while a standard MPC objective with saturation afterwards gives a perfectly fine simulation. A-posteriori I mean the standard hack of simply solving the unconstrained problem and then saturating the control.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thank you for your help and answers.